# How to control system volume using java script

Tags: javascript

I would like to control system volume(if possible per process also), using java script.
I googled but coudn't able to find a way to do this, please advice.

I am targeting to write platform independent code , is it possible through java, if yes then how can I put this to work from my existing C++ code.

Comment: why have you tagged this with javascript it is sandboxed in browser

Comment: You do realize that java and javascript are quite different technologies?

Comment: Do you want to use Java or Javascript?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: Sure making it work in your "existing C++" code seems like a way to go. You won't be able to do it through JavaScript or Java.

Comment: First find diffrence between java and javascript

Comment: I knew both Java/ Java script are two different thing. Looking for solution from java script if it is possible else in worst case I would like to write a code in java, and can invoke this process from my C++ app.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is run in a browser, so that won't help you control the system.  And I'm afraid Java can't control system volume.  It can only control the volume of a certain sound file being played through it.